# How to take a list of strings and change it into an object with string properties?

Tags: c#, list

I have a Dictionary of `List<string>`, where each element looks like this:

```
(key): '23895'
(List<string>): ['00185801']
```

I want to convert it into an object that has these strings as properties:

```
title: '23895'
orderNumber: '00185801'
```

The way that I am doing it right now is, I have a class `OrderNumber`:

```
namespace myApp
{
    class OrderNumber
    {
        public string title;
        public string orderNumber;

        public OrderNumber(string title, string orderNumber)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

And I convert a Dictionary of `List<string>` to a `List<OrderNumber>` as follows:

```
    private void convertDictListsToObjects(Dictionary<string,List<string>> orderNumberDict)
    {
        orderNumberObjList = new List<OrderNumber>();
        foreach(string key in orderNumberDict.Keys){
            List<string> orderNumberList=orderNumberDict[key];
            OrderNumber orderNumberObj = new OrderNumber(key, orderNumberList[0]);
            orderNumberObjList.Add(orderNumberObj);
        }
    }
```

I have several different types of `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`, with different numbers of elements in the `List<string>`, and my goal is to use an `Enumerable.Join()` on them, but I need to convert them into lists of objects with property names like the `OrderNumber` class above in order to perform the `.Join()`.  Is there a simpler way to do this than the way I'm already using, or do i need to use this technique, making a separate class for each type of `List<string>`?

Comment: if i understand correctly, if you have for the key `23895` more than one element in `List<string>`, you want to convert it to 2 objects in the new list `List<OrderNumber>` with duplicated `title`? if not exactly what you want, you can add an example for the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change implementation of `convertDictListsToObjects` to this:

```
private void convertDictListsToObjects(Dictionary<string, List<string>> orderNumberDict)
{
    var orderNumberObjList = orderNumberDict
        .Select(p => new
        {
            title = p.Key,
            orderNumber = p.Value.First()
        });
}
```

Generate the same `Anonymous type` list for all of your dictionaries and do your join.

(if you are confused about it, update your method signature with proper input and output of what you need and let me know to help you)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make these `anonymous type` object lists available outside the function, because I want to decouple creating the lists and performing the join.  Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: @sigil : `Anonymouse types` are only suitable for local usage, they shouldn't being used out of their scope. I have no idea about your other objects and dictionaries but as you said you want to join them I realized that you have almost common property set for your objects, so you can define a general object that cover all property sets of your objects and use it instead of anonymous type

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary<K, V>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`. Use the `System.Linq.Select` to transform each `KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>` of your dictionary into an OrderNumber instance.

```
    private IEnumerable<OrderNumber> ConvertDictListsToObjects(Dictionary<string, List<string>> orderNumberDict)
    {
        return orderNumberDict.Select(pair => new OrderNumber(pair.Key, pair.Value?.FirstOrDefault()));
    }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.